# L2Tp forming session, but not tunnel (Cisco)

Tags: router, vpn, l2tp, switching, cisco-router

**Two cisco routers
For some reason they establish a session but not a tunnel. The session says:**

LocID RemID TunID username, Intf/vcid, Circuit State Last Chg Uniq ID
1     2     n/a     1, Gi0/1                   Est      3d19h 0

**The "show l2tp tunnel" displays:**

%No active L2tp tunnels

**R1:**

Interface GigabitThernet0/0
ip address X.X.X.X 255.255.255.224
duplex auto
speed auto
no cdp enable

Interface GigabitEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
xconnect X.X.X.X 1 encapsulation l2tpv3 manual pw-class TEST
l2tp id 1 2

pseudowire-class TEST
encapsulation l2tpv3
protocol none
ip local interface GigabitEthernet0/0

**R2:**

Interface G0/0.147
encapsulation dot1q 147
xconnect x.x.x.x 1 encapsulation l2tp manual pw-class LVC
l2tp id 2 1

pseudowire-class LVC
encapsulation l2tpv3
protocol none
ip local interface Loopback147

Answer (score 0):

It should be either DOT1Q both sides or Physical interfaces both sides.

One side Physical interface and other side DOT1Q wont work.